# KubeApps: Invalid GetAvailablePackageSummaries response from the plugin helm.packages: ... Unable to fetch chart categories

Tags: k3s, kubeapps

I followed the [setup instructions for `k3s`, and `kubectl` in this answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/16109/18965). I'm getting this error when I boot into KubeApps

> An error occurred while fetching the catalog: Invalid GetAvailablePackageSummaries response from the plugin helm.packages: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Unable to fetch chart categories: pq: relation "charts" does not exist.

How can I resolve this error?

[image: Picture of the Error]

When I pull the logs, I see,

> I0608 21:01:12.935502       1 root.go:32] asset-syncer has been configured with: `server.Config{DatabaseURL:"kubeapps-postgresql:5432", DatabaseName:"assets", DatabaseUser:"postgres", DatabasePassword:"E0mn56sa5d", Debug:false, Namespace:"kubeapps", OciRepositories:[]string{}, TlsInsecureSkipVerify:false, FilterRules:"", PassCredentials:false, UserAgent:"asset-syncer/2.4.5 (kubeapps/2.4.5)", UserAgentComment:"kubeapps/2.4.5", GlobalReposNamespace:"kubeapps", KubeappsNamespace:"", AuthorizationHeader:"", DockerConfigJson:""}`

Followed by,

```
Usage:
  asset-syncer sync [REPO NAME] [REPO URL] [REPO TYPE] [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help                       help for sync
      --oci-repositories strings   List of OCI Repositories in case the type is OCI
      --version                    version for sync

Global Flags:
      --add_dir_header                   If true, adds the file directory to the header of the log messages
      --alsologtostderr                  log to standard error as well as files
      --database-name string             Name of the database to use (default "charts")
      --database-url string              Database URL (default "localhost:5432")
      --database-user string             Database user
      --debug                            verbose logging
      --filter-rules string              JSON blob with the rules to filter assets
      --global-repos-namespace string    Namespace for global repos (default "kubeapps")
      --log_backtrace_at traceLocation   when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
      --log_dir string                   If non-empty, write log files in this directory
      --log_file string                  If non-empty, use this log file
      --log_file_max_size uint           Defines the maximum size a log file can grow to. Unit is megabytes. If the value is 0, the maximum file size is unlimited. (default 1800)
      --logtostderr                      log to standard error instead of files (default true)
      --namespace string                 Namespace of the repository being synced
      --one_output                       If true, only write logs to their native severity level (vs also writing to each lower severity level)
      --pass-credentials                 pass credentials to all domains
      --skip_headers                     If true, avoid header prefixes in the log messages
      --skip_log_headers                 If true, avoid headers when opening log files
      --stderrthreshold severity         logs at or above this threshold go to stderr (default 2)
      --tls-insecure-skip-verify         Skip TLS verification
      --user-agent-comment string        UserAgent comment used during outbound requests
  -v, --v Level                          number for the log level verbosity (default 3)
      --vmodule moduleSpec               comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging
```

As well as this errors,

> Error: Error: Get `https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/index.yaml`: dial tcp: lookup charts.bitnami.com on 10.43.0.10:53: server misbehaving

---

I filed a bug upstream, but I'm not sure if this is a bug or a misconfiguration:

- https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/kubeapps/issues/4882#issue-1265184794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Upstream Answer -- Networking Problem.

Though I'm getting this on a fresh install I was guided to this which indicates a bigger problem,

```
kubectl -n kubeapps exec deployment/kubeapps -- curl -sI https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/index.yaml
```

this returns "command terminated with exit code 6".

I can further identify the problem with `nslookup`, without using Kube Apps by following the [k3s tutorial on troubleshooting dns]https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/troubleshooting/dns/)

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never busybox --image=busybox:1.28 -- nslookup www.google.com
```

### Follow up

Now that I know what this problem is (with external DNS resolution), I've asked this question for more information [Newly installed k3s cluster on fresh OS install can not resolve external domains, when the host can?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/newly-installed-k3s-cluster-on-fresh-os-install-can-not-resolve-external-domains)